# How to disable only Vertical Scrolling in WebView Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a page with WebView and other UI elements. Entire page is inside a scrollView. I want the WebView to be height of content which i had already achieved but still the scroll of WebView are active. I want to disable only vertical scrolling on WebView but Horizontal Scrolling should be enabled.

I had already written CustomRenderer to calculate the height of the content of WebView so i need to do something to only disable Vertical Scrolling. This is something possible to do?

Comment: If you disable the vertical scrolling and run the app or a smaller screen, what will happened to the content

Comment: My WebView is inside the scrollView so the entire screen scrolls. I think i missed that in my question.

Comment: I recall seeing another question about this the other day. Can you please include some code? Thanks

Comment: @ArunGupta This doesn't make sense, if you put views in a scrollview, the views will scroll not what inside of them. Including the web view, the whole thing will scroll regardless of the content of the WebView.

I guess that is outside the scope of your question so it doesn't matter, but I don't think what are you doing is user friendly.

There are horizontal list views and you can make scrollview scroll horizontally

Comment: @Ali123 Thats my requirement. I have screen which is more then the screen height and contains WebView, ListView... So i want all the contents to fit there height and let only ScrollView do the scrolling.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: Nope. Not able to disable the vertical scrolling. I had to add 10-20 px to the calculated height in order to give some padding to webview.